# Databinding for checkbox with stringvalues

Tags: c#, data-binding, datarow

I have to bind datarows to my controls. So far so good. The problem now is, that my datarow contains only strings in the column I have to bind, but of course the property "checked" of a Checkbox takes only boolean arguments.

Is there a way to use DataBinding here? Maybe with some kind of converter in between?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using as a string representation of the boolean value? 'True'/'False'? '1'/'0'? Some code might help, preferably the code in which you bind the controls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [ConvertEventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.converteventhandler(VS.71).aspx) to change types for DataBinding.

Example

```
    Binding binding = new Binding("checked", dt, "string_field");
    binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Format);
    binding.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Parse);
    this.checkbox1.DataBindings.Add(binding); 

    void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString() == "yep") e.Value = true;
        else e.Value = false;
    }

    void binding_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.Value) e.Value = "yep";
        else e.Value = "nope";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

But still one question. Will the ConvertEventHandler also transform my values back into the string when it goes down to the database. I mean, DataBinding is meant to cover both ways.

Comment: Yes it can transform back to string using the Parse event.  I have updated the example to show this.

Comment: Great thanks. But one comment: you have to set the formattingEnabled, otherwise the Format-event is never called. Binding binding = new Binding("checked", dt, "string_field", true); works

Comment: Is it possible to bind a checkbox to an int rather than a string? Specifically, I want to bind it so that when the checkbox is checked, the field is set to 100 and when it's cleared the field is set to 0.